# Resetting OutputStream so updated variables send

Tags: java

I've come across an issue when sending an object over a local connection. The object **will send the first time as expected**. However variables of the object are **constantly being changed** therefore need to be updated when sending to the other connection. This is done through sending messages prompting the other client to listen and wait for the object being sent.

I'm aware that the java.io.ObjectOutputStream.reset() method exists but keep getting the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
         output.reset();
```

Here's how the code is currently structured (Minus lots of non relevant code):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*
import java.io.*;

public class Client
{
    private static Socket cSocket = null;        
    private static ObjectOutput output = null;

    private static Person myPerson = null;

    private static String serverHost = "localhost";

    public void Run()
    { 
         // Declaring the output
         output = new ObjectOutputStream(
            cSocket.getOutputStream()
         );

    }

    private static void sendPerson() 
    {
       try 
       {
          output.writeObject( myPerson ); 
          output.reset();
       } catch (Exception e) 
       {
      
       }
    }
}
```

TLDR: Each time sendPerson() is called the other client receives the first object sent to the other client rather than the updated variables. Tried using reset(); but error is thrown.

Would just like the objects updated variables to be sent rather than the initial object always being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `ObjectOutputStream#reset` you have to define your field with such type.

Not `ObjectOutput`, but `ObjectOutputStream`.

Like this:

```
private static ObjectOutputStream output = null;
```